# R shiny - stop() in eventReactive without error message in console

Tags: r, shiny

I just new in Shiny, and i have problem. i have a event reactive and the stop function inside. when I run my code(no checkbox and do click button), the shiny is work well. but in console display the error message "eventReactiveHandler". do you have a solution for my problem? i want to no error message in my console. 
and i not expect the solution is

```
opt <- options(show.error.messages=FALSE)
on.exit(options(opt))
```

because the error will not display in my all code, i want just specifically in this error.
thank you... this is the code...

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
var.x<-reactiveValues()
shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxGroupInput("indepvar","Independent Variable",
                             choices = c("1"=1,"2"=2)),
          actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("coba"),
          uiOutput("popup4")
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$coba <- renderUI({
        gendata()
        indep<-NULL
        for(i in 1:length(var.x)){
          indep <- paste(indep,var.x[i],",")
        }
        list(
          renderText(indep)
        )
      })

      gendata<- eventReactive(input$tabBut,{

      if(is.null(input$indepvar)){
        stop()
      }

          var.x<<- input$indepvar  


      })

      output$popup4 <- renderUI({

        if(!is.null(input$indepvar))return()

        list(
          bsModal("modalExample4", "Peringatan", "tabBut", size = "small",wellPanel(
            "Anda belum memilih independent variabel..."
          ))
        )

      })

        }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise suppressing error messages, as there are in there for you, I suggest you look into `validate` and `need` in `shiny`, you can go read [validation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) article

To `quickfix` you issue you can just return NULL

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
var.x<-reactiveValues()
shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxGroupInput("indepvar","Independent Variable",
                             choices = c("1"=1,"2"=2)),
          actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("coba")
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$coba <- renderUI({
        gendata()
        indep<-NULL
        for(i in 1:length(var.x)){
          indep <- paste(indep,var.x[i],",")
        }
        list(
          renderText(indep)
        )
      })

      gendata<- eventReactive(input$tabBut,{

        if(is.null(input$indepvar)){
          var.x <<- NULL
          return(NULL)
          stop()
        }

        var.x<<- input$indepvar  


      })

    }
)
```

Comment: thank you, but with return(NULL) is not work in my real code (check edit). when no checkbox and click button the error will be displayed " Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed."

Comment: Why did you add `var.x <<- NULL`? as per my other example? I have added the change

Comment: no,  I have my bsmodal for validation when var.x<-NULL, check my code (new edit)

Comment: Either way, there are not errors in the console, as `    var.x <<- NULL
          return(NULL)
          stop()` solves it. This answers your original question

Comment: when "return(NULL)" not in the code, error is display in console as the function stop(),

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things as per the code below:

- Make sure that `gendata` returns nothing when there are no independent variables selected (see lines 37-40). This stops your original error message
- Make sure that `output$coba` is not evaluated when `gendata` has no value (see line 25)

Hope this helps,
John

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
var.x<-reactiveValues()
shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxGroupInput("indepvar","Independent Variable",
                             choices = c("1"=1,"2"=2)),
          actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("coba"),
          uiOutput("popup4")
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$coba <- renderUI({
        req(gendata())
        indep<-NULL
        for(i in 1:length(var.x)){
          indep <- paste(indep,var.x[i],",")
        }
        list(
          renderText(indep)
        )
      })

      gendata<- eventReactive(input$tabBut,{

        if(is.null(input$indepvar)) {
          var.x <<- NULL
          return()
        }

        var.x<<- input$indepvar  

      })

      output$popup4 <- renderUI({

        if(!is.null(input$indepvar))return()

        list(
          bsModal("modalExample4", "Peringatan", "tabBut", size = "small",wellPanel(
            "Anda belum memilih independent variabel..."
          ))
        )

      })

    }
)
```